# Como colocar imagenes en intellij idea

Tags: html, imagen, intellij-idea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cargo mi archivo html no sale la imagen, segun yo ya puse o la direccion de la imagen, pero marca error en la imagen, no se si la agrege mal o este mal en otra cosa.
me pueden ayudar.

o tambian como agregar imagenes en intellij idea

Comment: En efecto está mal tu ruta. Tu ruta debe ser algo así `<img src="../../java/mx.edu.utez.sigebuapp/Estilos/LOGO-SIGUEBU2.png">` Como podrás ver, debes recorrer atrás dos directorios (Templates y luego webapp)

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. no pongas imágenes donde debería ir código, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.